# How to account for categorical variables in calculating a risk score from regression model?

Tags: r, regression

I have a data set which has a number of variables that I'd like to use to generate a risk score for getting a disease.

I have created a basic version of what I'm trying to do.

The dataset looks like this:

```
ID  DISEASE_STATUS  AGE  SEX  LOCATION
1   1               20   1    FRANCE
2   0               22   1    GERMANY
3   0               24   0    ITALY
4   1               20   1    GERMANY
5   1               20   0    ITALY
```

So the model I ran was:

```
glm(disease_status ~ age + sex + location, data=data, family=binomial(link='logit'))
```

The beta values produced by this model were as follows:

```
bage = −0.193
bsex = −0.0497
blocation= 1.344
```

To produce a risk score, I want to multiply the values for each individual by the beta values, eg:

```
risk score = (-0.193 * 20 (age)) + (-0.0497 * 1 (sex)) + (1.344 * ??? (location))
```

However, what value would I use to multiply the beta score for location by?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide the data.frame with `dput` in the post?